# Postgres is ignoring my GIN index on an array (strings) column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, indexing

I have an array column (of strings) on a Students table. This column may potentially (and commonly) hold hundreds of elements.

For one of my queries, I compare another array (also which may have hundreds of elements) against that array using the `&&` operator to see if there are any overlaps. It looks like this:

```
SELECT students.*
FROM students
WHERE (students.read_allow_sids && ARRAY['long', 'list', 'of', 'strings'])
AND NOT (students.read_deny_sids && ARRAY['long', 'list', 'of', 'strings'])
```

In my test db the students table has about 10k records. However, my query takes about 4.5s to complete with a sequential scan (way too long! bleh).

To improve performance I added a GIN index to the array (within Rails migration):

```rb
add_index :students, :read_allow_sids, using: 'gin'
add_index :students, :read_deny_sids, using: 'gin'
```

I noticed using EXPLAIN that my new index was being ignored in favor of a sequential scan. I temporarily disabled it using `SET enable_seqscan TO OFF;` to check the performance of the index. Lo and behold, once the query started using the index, it went from 4.5s -> 200ms (about 20x faster!).

---

EDIT: here is the output of the EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for the query (with seq scan turned ON vs OFF)

With it ON:

```sql
Seq Scan on public.students (cost=0.00..970.57 rows=786 width=522) (actual time=3.429..4319.502 rows=1698 loops=1)
  Output: id, classroom_id, created_at, updated_at, user_id, read_allow_sids, read_deny_sids, write_allow_sids, write_deny_sids
  Filter: ((students.read_allow_sids && '{long, list, of, strings}'::character varying[]) AND (NOT (students.read_deny_sids && '{long, list, of, strings}'::character varying[])))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 9554
  Buffers: shared hit=803
Planning Time: 20.932 ms
Execution Time: 4320.698 ms
```

With it OFF:

```sql
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.students  (cost=1734.59..2634.39 rows=786 width=522) (actual time=127.219..137.151 rows=1698 loops=1)
  Output: id, classroom_id, created_at, updated_at, user_id, read_allow_sids, read_deny_sids, write_allow_sids, write_deny_sids
  Recheck Cond: (students.read_allow_sids && '{long, list, of, strings}'::character varying[])
  Filter: (NOT (students.read_deny_sids && '{long, list, of, strings}'::character varying[]))
  Heap Blocks: exact=549
  Buffers: shared hit=1390
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_students_on_read_allow_sids  (cost=0.00..1734.40 rows=6453 width=0) (actual time=126.842..126.843 rows=1698 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (students.read_allow_sids && '{long, list, of, strings}'::character varying[])
        Buffers: shared hit=841
Planning Time: 21.460 ms
Execution Time: 137.890 ms
```

---

I expect the postgres query planner to choose the most optimal choice (i.e. the GIN index) when it is planning the query, but it does not. The query is pretty simple to begin with...it's unclear how I would alter it to make the query planner prefer the index. I'm already familiar with the fact Postgres does not have "hints." I've also already tried running ANALYZE on the students table to update its stats, but the query planner still opts for a seq scan.

So the big questions are:

1. If the index is so much faster, why is the query planner preferring the seq scan?
2. More importantly, how can we get the query planner to prefer the index (i.e. plan correctly) using a methodology that is viable in a production env?

Comment: Nobody can tell why, can they? You haven't posted an EXPLAIN ANALYZE or similar.

Comment: Could you please share the results from `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` for your SQL statement? (in plain text, as an update to your question)

Comment: By the way, what is your configuration setting for random_page_costs ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I apologize, I have added the EXPLAIN outputs to the question.

The `random_page_costs` is set to the default (4.0), but I played around with setting it to 1.0, 1.1, etc, with no effect.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I apologize, I've added the EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) output to the question

Answer (score 0):

The costs for the index scan are much higher, 2634.39 vs 970.57 for the sequential scan. When this doesn't reflect the real-world situation, you can lower random_page_costs and/or cpu_index_tuple_cost to favor an index scan.

```
SET random_page_costs TO 1.1; -- close to seq_page_cost
SET cpu_tuple_cost TO 0.1; -- to increate the sequential scan costs
SET cpu_index_tuple_cost TO 0.001; -- to lower the costs for an index scan
```

And run `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` again. You should now see a different result for the costs of the query, and maybe a different/better query plan.

When you find a setting that works for this query, and for the rest of your queries, you can set the into postgresql.conf or as a property of your database.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET random_page_cost TO 1.1;
-- or:
ALTER DATABASE your_database SET random_page_cost TO 1.1;
```

When done:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf(); -- as superuser
```

You could also set this per database role.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately, updating these values did not work. I did play around with changing them in various directions to see how it changed the cost. The only way I could get it to favor the index was by setting `random_page_cost` to `0.5` (with `seq_page_cost` at `1.0`). According to postgres docs, setting `random` value lower than `seq` doesn't make any sense. Altering `cpu_index_tuple_cost` did not significantly affect the cost. Do these results turn on any lightbulbs in your head? I found them surprising/confusing

Comment: @some_guy I have to see the query plans and see how the costs changed. The planner uses the plan with the lowest costs. Something else you could do, is changing the number of statistics for this table. The planner did expect 6453 rows from the index scan, while it could find just 1698 rows. You could use ALTER TABLE ... SET ... STATISTICS ? or your use CREATE STATISTICS to create some custom stats for the combination of these two columns.

Comment: @some_guy What is the maximum value you used for cpu_tuple_cost? And what happens to your query plans when you crank it up even further? Check the costs for both plans, that determines what plan will be used

Comment: SETTINGS: seq_page_cost = 1.0; random_page_cost = 0.5; seq_page_cost
cpu_tuple_cost = 0.1; cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.001.
--- The EXPLAIN:---
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.enrollments  (cost=469.72..1963.41 rows=801 width=541) (actual time=2152.797..2164.859 rows=1698 loops=1)
  Heap Blocks: exact=569
  Buffers: shared hit=1460
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_enrollments_on_read_allow_sids  (cost=0.00..469.52 rows=6578 width=0) (actual time=2152.448..2152.450 rows=1769 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=891
Planning Time: 27.297 ms
Execution Time: 2165.705 ms

Comment: If I do same settings EXCEPT change cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.0025
--- EXPLAIN ---
Seq Scan on public.enrollments  (cost=0.00..1984.46 rows=801 width=541) (actual time=2.934..4396.847 rows=1698 loops=1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 9554
  Buffers: shared hit=803
Planning Time: 27.232 ms
Execution Time: 4398.419 ms

Comment: But in both cases I have a random_page_cost set lower than seq_page_cost, which is nonsensical. I'd like to avoid changing db settings significantly if possible, as I'm concerned about how that might affect *other* queries in the db. If it makes any difference, it's worth noting that the array cols that have the GIN index potentially have hundreds of items

Comment: cost=469.72..1963.41 for the sequential scan and cost=1734.59..2634.39 for the index scan. The issue is most likely the (large) number of values in your arrays, for each value there will be another random page scan when using the index. For a sequential scan that doesn't matter, you're gonna read every value in the table anyway. You have to change the database configuration for the planner settings, that's standard procedure. And you need a regression test for all or most of your queries.